# Segmentation fault on integer declaration

Tags: c

I'm getting a segmentation fault with this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

void dsort(int a[], int start, int end){
    int l = end - start + 1; //this is the line it is segfaulting
    if(l == 2){
        if(a[end] > a[start]){
            int temp = a[start];
            a[start] = a[end];
            a[end] = temp;
        }
    }else{
        double calc = (2*l)/3;
        int m = ceil(calc);
        dsort(a, start, m - 1);
        dsort(a, end - m, end);
        dsort(a, start, m - 1);
    }
}
int main(){
    int a[4] = {3,4,2,5};
    int start = 0;
    int end = 4-1;
    dsort(a,start,end);
    int  i = 0;

    for(i; i<=3;i++){
        printf("%i\n",a[i]);
    }
}
```

I'm not really sure why it is segfaulting at that spot. Anyone know how to fix that?

Comment: Almost certainly because you're writing off the end of the buffer somewhere, and thus corrupting the stack.

Comment: What is the point of making `calc` `double` if `(2 * l) / 3` is an `int`? Or did you want to make something like `(2.0 * l) / 3`?

Comment: Why do you think it is segfaulting on that line? What tools have you tried using?

Comment: @IskarJarak Well I used gdb to find the location of the segfault. But I'm not really sure why. I think I am overflowing the stack but don't understand how to fix that.

Comment: @kraskevich Well (2*l) / 3 won't always evaluate to an int. ie when l = 4;

Comment: @user2923535 That is not how integer division works in C. It truncates, so (2*4)/3 = 2.

Comment: @user2923535 If you try a memory checking tool such as valgrind (as well as gdb, not instead of), you will find that the segfault is caused by a stack overflow.

Comment: Note: Simplify `double calc = (2*l)/3; int m = ceil(calc);` --> `m = (2*l + (3-1))/3;`

Comment: Note: `if(l == 2){` --> `if(l <= 2){`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The program fails at that point coincidentally: it recurs indefinitely until it runs out of stack space.

Comment: **OP**: you must be careful with recursion to prevent running into this problem.